# I have inputs in div why my code makes Array with arrays instead of array of value

Tags: javascript

I have a form with many inputs each on in div i need to make and array of input values instead of array of arrays with values.

```js
var arr = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form__option"),
    function(block) {
      return [].map.call(block.querySelectorAll(".field"), function(inp) {
            return inp.value;
```

```html
<div id='form__option3' class="form__option form__option3">
  <input id="Input NameShipper" type="text" class="InputReciever field" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use `flatMap()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why don't you just directly select the inputs by class then push their values inside array

```
var InputReciever = document.getElementsByClassName("InputReciever");
var arr = []
for(let i = 0; i < InputReciever.length; i++) { 
  arr.push(InputReciever[i].value);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: If this solved your code please mark this answer as true

Answer (score -1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), returns a `nodeList` i.e. an `Array`, you might wanna map it's data to values (with inp.value) and spread it like this.
`return ...mapedValues`